# Pressure done by a bar/beam inserted in a continuous medium (wall)

Tags: continuum-mechanics, applied-physics

Related to a DIY project, I'm facing the following question:

[image]

Assume a metal bar (beam) of square section,  $a \times a$, is inserted partially in a continuous medium (lets say, a wall) in a way that $h$ of the beam is inside the medium and $l$ is outside of the wall, and a force $F=200 N$ is done in the other extreme of the bar, perpendicular to it. The question is: how the pressure ( the force per unit area, $N/mm^2$ ) is distributed **in the contact surfaces between the cantilever beam and the wall** ?

Note: we could say that the beam has no weight, no friction forces and the system is stable, no displacements. An infinite wall in width, height and thickness. If easier, we can consider a beam of circular section instead of square.

Inside the wall the beam has 5 surfaces: right, left, top, bottom and back. In the ideal case of no friction, I think forces in right and left surfaces will be null. No idea if forces in back and top are also null. Force in bottom must allow to keep fixed all system, with an unknown distribution of pressure on it ( uniform? maximum at $h$ deep? ).

I've no knowledge to solve it as a continuous problem. A strong simplification that came to my mind is consider the system as equivalent to a lever with lengths $h$ and $l$, being the support axe the red line in the draw. That means to the force in the other extreme of the beam (green line in the draw) will be $F' = F \frac {l}{h}$. By example if h=5cm and l=50 cm, then $F'=200*50/5=2000N$.

Background: if we stand a TV of 20 kg using a $l=50 cm$ beam, how to estimate the forces over the wall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows a combination of a steel rod and a concrete wall in 3D. The rod is embedded in the wall 1/6 of the length. Section of a rod 1x1. We take the effective force divided by the cross-sectional area as 1. The middle picture is the distribution of the vertical component of the deformations in the wall; in the right-hand picture, this is the distribution of the $\sigma_{zz}$ stress component. It can be seen that in such a situation, a stress increase of 30 times can be obtained. The calculations are performed using FEM and Mathematica 12.
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Very good answer. Has been some weight applied to the free extreme of the rod ? When you say "stress increase of 30", relative to what ? Could you post the Mathematica commands ?

Comment: The force F is applied to the free end. The component of the stress tensor is normalized to $F/a^2$  in your notation. I will post the code on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions and give a link, there it will be possible to discuss method.

Comment: So if I were to apply the exact same force  $F$ (same load) , but taking $a/2$ as the height and $ a/2$ for the width of the beam , you're saying that the maximum stress on the wall would be multiplied by 4 and yield an increase of stress of 120?

Comment: @user8736288 Yes of course. The pressure increases if we reduce the area while maintaining force. Why do we use a knife with a sharp blade when we cut something?

Comment: I think the area in question for the pressure seen by the wall isn't $a^{2}$ but rather $ha$,  the surface normal to the $zz$ axis of your numerical model, and $a$,is the width of the beam. If the applied force  remains constant, the force exerted on the wall will also be the same. Since stress if the force divided by the area ($ha$) , isn't it a bit strange to normalise the problem by $a^{2}$? The problem should only scale with the width of the beam, not its height.

Comment: @user8736288 How can this affect the solution to the problem?

Comment: @Alex Trounev It was just to point out that, in general, it cannot be assumed that the maximum stress in the wall can be taken as $\approx 30 F/ a^{2}$ whatever values taken for $a$ and $h$, even if we keep the same ratio $h/L$ you did. Great numerical modelling, anyway!

Comment: @user8736288 Thank you! I have given only one option for a given square steel bar. But a variety of other options are possible. In any case, in the theory of elasticity, we can choose only one linear scale, for example, $a$, and one force scale, for example, $F/a^2$. All other parameters enter the equations as dimensionless.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by distribution of the "pressure", but this is a static problem involving a cantilever beam. The beam inside the wall is ignored. First from a static equilibrium perspective, there has to be an upward reaction force exerted by the wall of 200 N for vertical equilibrium to counter the downward 200 N force. There also has to be a counter-clock wise moment reaction at the wall of 200N x 50 cm = 10000 N.cm to counteract the clockwise moment (the "rotational effect") of 10000 N.cm due to the 200 N load.

The beam is subjected to an internal bending moment as well as a vertical shear force throughout the exposed portion.  The vertical shear force divided by the beam cross section is the shear stress. Stress has units of force per unit area, just like pressure. So maybe that is what you are thinking of. The bending moment creates tensile and compressive stresses at the extremes (top and bottom bottom of the beam, respectively).

Bending moment is a maximum at the wall and zero at the free end. Shear force is constant throughout and equals 200 N. If you look at the shear and moment diagrams for the cantilever with a force at the end, you will see the shear is constant and the moment linearly increasing progressing from the free end to the wall.

This is the best I can give you without more detail, and without being sure what you mean by pressure. You really need to take a statics and mechanics of materials course to progress.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I should use stress instead of pressure. What I'm asking is the force per unit area (N/mm^2) in the surfaces of the beam that is in contact with the wall. An intuitive result (probably wrong) is that the most inner part of the wall will do down force over the beam, while the most external part will made a up force, being null the force ath/2. Question edited.

Comment: "The beam inside the wall is ignored": This is the part I'm interested on, the surfaces of the beam inside the wall. Inside the wall the beam has 5 surfaces: right, left, top, bottom and back. In the ideal case of no friction, I think forces in right and left surfaces will be null. No idea if forces in back and top are also null. Force in bottom must allow to keep fixed all system, with a unknown pressure distribution on it.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Interesting questions not normally addressed in basic cantilever beam analysis. In real cantilevers the beam and "wall" are often one inseparable unit, and the "wall" may not actually be a wall but some other type of support. But let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I don't think the issue is whether or not the wall will support it. I think failure is most likely to occur in the beam where the beam enters the wall rather than any failure within the wall. And the failure would most likely be a bending stress failure where the bending stress is tension on the top fibers of the wall. Kind of like bending and snapping a twig. Vertical stresses in the wall are transmitted through the bulk likely spread downward like a a column in compression. But I do not pretend to be a structural engineer, to take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I still think the weak point is bending stress in the beam as the surface of the wall and that stresses inside the wall are comparatively spread out, or "diluted". But you really need input from a structural engineer. A search on cantilever beam failure turned up the following link for an example like ours. The answer seems to support my thinking.  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/cantilever-beam-failure-as-a-function-of-force-applied-to-free-end.649596/

Comment: @pasabaporaqui "I remove all wall upper to the beam, the beam will fail" If you remove all wall upper to beam there will be no moment resistance by the wall and the beam will simply rotate. Not sure what you mean by "fail" but to me it is a material failure of something, not the lack of equilibrium. 200 N is only 45 lb-f. Pretty weak wall to not be able to support 45 lb. At any rate I think I have taken this about as far as I can. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good pratice in structural engineering to check that both the beam material and  the material supporting the beam can withstand the loads. The admissible pressure for the wall of course  depends on the type of material and could vary from say few tens of bars for bricks to over 100 bars for concrete. Solving exactly your problem might not be so easy.  A possible simple approach is to model the wall material as a distribution of very stiff springs reacting at the bottom and on the top of the beam to the moment and shear stress imposed by the load. I would suggest to use the reacting stress on the beam as shown in  diagram a). The resulting reactions on the beam are shown in b). The 2 equations of equilibrium (moment and resultant) make it possible to solve for $R_{top}$ and $R_{bot}$. Since $R_{bot}=R_{top}+ P$, the max stress will be at the bottom and worth $\sigma_{max}=2R_{bot}/ha$, $ha$ being the surface of the beam resting on the wall material.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However,   the relation between P, l and Rtop (or Rbottom) seems missing.